# Why are promise callback result types not strictly checked?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, I have an interface `MyInterface` defined as below:

```
interface MyInterface {
    hello: string
}
```

Using it to define an object does not allow me to include properties which are not described by the interface. The following produces an error indicating that the property `what` is not allowed because it is not defined in `MyInterface`:

```
const testObject: MyInterface = {
    hello: 'world',
    what: 'is going on',
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

However, using it as a promise result type allows me to return properties that are not defined in `MyInterface`; the following does not produce an error:

```
const testPromise: Promise<MyInterface> = Promise.resolve({
    hello: 'world',
    what: 'is going on',
});
```

Is it reasonable to expect the same error to occur in the second snippet? If not, is there a way to make the return type of the promise strict as in the object assignment example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're calling "strict" is conventionally referred to as "[exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)". Exact object types would only accept the specific properties mentioned in their definitions, whereas inexact or "open" types will accept extra properties.  In TypeScript, types are generally treated as open and not exact.  This is very good for subtyping and extending interfaces:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  b: number
}

const bar: Bar = {a: "hey", b: 123};
const foo: Foo = bar; // okay
```

If `Foo` were exact, then `Bar` would not be a valid extension of `Foo`, and `bar` would not be a valid instance of `Foo`, and just about the whole interface/class subtyping/extension/inheritance features of the language would be broken.

---

But it was discovered that this kind of open type didn't catch a common class of bugs, where people would misspell an optional property's key.  If the property is optional, then it's okay to leave it out, and if object types are open, then the misspelled key is just some extra property.  To deal with this, the language also does [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) for which, *in very limited circumstances*, some types are treated as if they were exact.

Specifically, this only happens when you are trying to use a brand new ("fresh") object literal in a place that expects a concrete object type.  So the following, as you saw, would be an error:

```
const excessError: Foo = { a: "hey", b: 123 }; // error!
//  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Foo'.
```

If you use an object literal in a place without an expected type, it will be accepted:

```
const noTypeExpected = { a: "hey", b: 123 }; // no error
```

And if you reuse an existing object literal type that isn't "fresh" anymore, it will be accepted:

```
const notBrandNew: Foo = noTypeExpected; // no error
```

And if you use pass an object literal through a generic function, the returned type will not be considered a "fresh" type anymore:

```
const identity = <T>(x: T) => x;
const alsoNotBrandNew: Foo = identity({ a: "hey", b: 123 }); // no error
```

---

So now let's look at the promise issue:

```
const promiseFoo: Promise<Foo> = Promise.resolve({ a: "hey", b: 123 }); // okay
```

This works because `Promise.resolve(value)` is a generic function with [the following signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L143):

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
  resolve<T>(value: T | PromiseLike<T>): Promise<T>;
}
```

The type parameter `T` is inferred from the type of `value`, which is `{a: string, b: number}`. So the return type is `Promise<{a: string, b: number}>`.  And that is assignable to `Promise<{a: string}>` (since `Promise` is [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in its type argument, which I won't get into here unless prompted) because that `{a: string, b: number}` type isn't considered a fresh object literal type anymore.

---

So, how can we get "exact" behavior out of `Promise.resolve()`?  The easiest way I can think of is to specify the generic type parameter manually as `Foo` instead of having it be inferred from the type of `value`:

```
const promiseExact = Promise.resolve<Foo>({ a: "hey", b: 123 }); // error!
// Object literal may only specify known properties, 
// and 'b' does not exist in type 'Foo | PromiseLike<Foo>'.
```

Now the error occurs because `Promise.resolve<Foo>(value)` expects `value` to be a `Foo | PromiseLike<Foo>`, and the fresh object literal is scrutinized as if it were of an exact type.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=60#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiKAQnFMhAB6QgAJmTSYc+QgCNSIAK4BbSdHqME6EBWSSupTtwC8OIqQBEACwgBPEwBotpAIwAmAMzI6AblxqNYZDExSDCxDbSgPZAB6SOR0AGs4S1V1TT4kMjIAUSgodCggsUNsY2RzK1t7ZGc3TyiY6FyoAEJcaIIAeUkAKwgEPwAbYBY4fuR5RNiQfstyAAde4BgZuJB0AHcQZFnc+agwYAgyOzghZABySTPkQXRD5FW-PmBNUGQwS3nz4LOAOmTfe7oAAqHwgmV48z6EEEyCKJTK1js0iqrncETaqx4OTy3hSfge7CgJ0EADkIGsCiFASD5uDIZBBOiYpiGjj-i9BBBwEMZoYADxAgB8AApeKQgQBKWGC5C8Lw+TQjMjoEnoMCE4lkimiKnATnc97C4okUoWRGVaruCVMwFYxrsvzbdDyZ4QYKkAAKuRdZAgfOCMsMXudrp+UEO6H6ADcIEb4WaKsjLXRrXVYgkkriAU6fWDeIg-EHvaHw8ro36A3GTQjE45USmbazmq0Yp0en1kINhqNxjN1NM5gslsgVutNk7dvtDnYW0RThcrjc7g8eLxnn5Xu9PmdgsgAD7IYO5gAywDiFcwgt+QA)

Comment: That's a great explanation, thanks @jcalz! How can this type of exact-ness be extended to return types in a promise callback further down the promise chain? i.e. `Promise.resolve<{}>({}).then<{}>(() => ({ extraProperty: 'foo' }))`.

Comment: There are two issues at play here. The first is that the generic parameter isn't quite close enough to your object literal to trigger the exact behaviour. The second is that `{}` is treated as a bit of a special case, and effectively opts you out of exact behaviour anyway. Something like `Promise.resolve<{}>({}).then((): {foo: string} => ({ foo: 'bar', extraProperty: 'foo' }))` would produce the desired error. They key is that instead of a function that later gets a type, it's the actual return type of the function that's specified.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TypeScript will allow you to write this, however, if you write

```
testPromise.then(value => value.what)
```

the compiler will then complain at this step.