# How can I make Typescript check that a return type is exactly matching a structure?

Tags: typescript

In this and other questions it's explained that return type for interfaces is not checked for 'extra' properties due to Typescript [excess-property-checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

> 1) [Why are promise callback result types not strictly checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512965/why-are-promise-callback-result-types-not-strictly-checked)
>
> 2) [Why does Typescript allowed incorrect plain object return for Interface definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525694/why-does-typescript-allowed-incorrect-plain-object-return-for-interface-definiti?noredirect=1#comment103378398_58525694)

In both cases Typescript only check that 'extra' are not allow, on creation of a variable.

**How I can make write a function definition in Typescript so that it will not accept 'extra' properties?**

> The code example that show the problem is [written here in a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3ud7) (please see it for clarification)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775790/forcing-excess-property-checking-on-variable-passed-to-typescript-function/54775885#54775885

Comment: @ShanonJackson Thank for the link. This is close to solving the problem, but it only works for parameters into a function, not to define the return type as I can see it.